mlDeploy Failed Using DHF 5.8
Facing below error while executing ./gradlew mlDeploy -i command.

Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging:
{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"400", "status":"Bad Request",
"messageCode":"MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD",
"message":"MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD: (err:FOER0000) Payload has errors in
structure, content-type or values. Role payload invalid."}}   Error
occurred while sending POST request to /manage/v2/roles; logging
request body to assist with debugging:
{"role-name":"%%mlHubAdminRole%%","description":"A role can deploy
modules to a data hub
instance.","role":["rest-admin","manage-admin","tde-admin"],"privilege":[{"privilege-name":"xdmp:set-server-field","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-set-server-field","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdmp:get-server-field","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-get-server-field","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"manage","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/manage","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdmp:eval","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-eval","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdmp:eval-in","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-eval-in","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdmp:invoke","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-invoke","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdmp:invoke-in","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-invoke-in","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdbc:invoke","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdbc-invoke","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdbc:invoke-in","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdbc-invoke-in","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdbc:eval","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdbc-eval","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdbc:eval-in","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdbc-eval-in","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdmp:document-load","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-document-load","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"xdmp:get-server-field-names","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-get-server-field-names","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"unprotected-collections","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/unprotected-collections","kind":"execute"},{"privilege-name":"any-uri","action":"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/any-uri","kind":"execute"}]}

Please suggest on how to get this issue fixed. We were successfully able to upgrade the "hubUpdate" with admin credentials using below command.
./gradlew hubUpdate -i

From what it logged: "role-name":"%%mlHubAdminRole%%", it appears that the %%mlHubAdminRole%% token was not replaced with the name of the mlHubAdminRole.
Is it possible that mlHubAdminRole property is not defined as you expected/intended?
To see all of the tokens that will be used for replacement, just run this task:
gradle mlPrintTokens
https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/wiki/Configuring-resources#new-in-version-320

I don't see mlHubAdminRole in the tokens list. I am running the deploy command with admin user. Also, when I try using non admin user, its erroring out as below

Task :hubDeploySecurity FAILED

Error occurred while sending POST request to /manage/v3; logging request body to assist with debugging: {}
Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":
{"statusCode":403,
"status":"Forbidden",
"message":"403 Forbidden"
}
}

mlHubAdminRole looks like a property from DHF 4.x and earlier, but it's not part of DHF 5.x. The role file with that in it and likely be deleted safely from your project.
